# Office 2016 activation process

Tags: license-key, microsoft-account, microsoft-office-2016, software-activation

We bought 10 licenses for MS Office 2016 Home & Business. I crashed with the activation problem and thanks God, I took note of which license I used in which workstation. I created a MS account for register all products under the same account. Everything happy, well, not exactly happy, but working.
Suddenly, from few days ago, one of the workstation said 'Office is not activate' and give the option for phone or online activation. I tried the online activation, but there is the list with all installations (Office, Office(1), ... Office(n)) and is hard to know which I must use.

1. I wrote the installation order, and this was the first workstation, so, I tried with the first from the list, but said is 'more than one installation using that license'. I don't know how MS organize that list.
2. Also, from *https://stores.office.com/myaccount > Install from a disc > I have a disc > View your product key*, I can see all keys for my products, but those are different keys, aren't the same from the boxes we got. Microsoft generate new keys in web? in that case don't have sense save the key cards because always MS will provide a new generated key?

**Question:** how to know which activation to use in every PC if the key in the MS account and the boxes are different??

Comment: Downvote without explication don't solve nothing: I don't know yet the solution, plus, I was punished for ask :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due Microsoft accounts have limited how many license can you add, I created more than one account with e-mail alias. Then I registered the Office key, but the most important is take note of which installation you install where. So, I created a simple table, with the key number in the card, with the PC name (and serial), and also, the Microsoft site shows other key number. Important also take care the order of installation, because there you won't see any description, you will see only a list: Office, Office (2), Office (3), ... and is important to know, because in case of reinstall, for activate, you must select which register belong to this concretely PC. Thanks God I don't have so many workstation with Office, but bigger network can be really a headache.
Finally, I have a table with this columns:

1. Key card number
2. Key online number
3. PC serial number
4. Installation order (first, second, etc.)
5. Account number under is registered the installation (usually an e-mail address)

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to the internet then it should automatically activate after you sign in to your account.

Comment: if you have more than one Office registered in your account it will ask for which one is (I don't understand why don't select it automatically?). For example: I have more than one in my account, so, when you login, it shows: Office, Office (2), Office (3)... (Office n), and you must select the right one.
But when you register the product the site generate another key, which is not the same key you have in the card. So, finally I wrote every key in the card, with the right key in the site, linking to the serial number of the device